# Toshiba laptop NB300 dual screen problems

Tags: windows-7, laptop, multiple-monitors

I have a Toshiba NB300 laptop with Windows 7 and it has one monitor port on the side.

I've have tried plugging in another monitor but it wont let me dual screen (ie 2 independent displays).

I can only do one screen or the orther, or duplicate screen.

Do I need to do something special to get dual screen? Is it just a limitation of my laptop?

Comment: Have you verified you have the latest graphic drivers and all Windows updates?

Answer (score 0):

This requires settings to be changed **both** on the laptop and in Windows 7. Once you get duplicate displays, you need to set Windows 7 to extend your desktop.

Here are some instructions how to do what you are asking;

[Dual monitor setup: Two monitors are better than one](http://www.microsoft.com/athome/organization/twomonitors.aspx#fbid=12yja-dpXPJ)

Comment: thanks i've done all that. but on that that drop down list where it should say 'extend displays' - it doesnt. i just have 'duplicate these screens' 'Show desktop only on 1' 'show desktop only on 2'

Comment: Sorry. You didn't mention that in your question. Those kind of details are helpful.

Comment: sorry. my bad. its my first question

Comment: Understood. It's no problem. I am just letting you know for future posts. There is great information in [ask] to help you.

Comment: ok. thanks. but regarding my screen... can you help? or is it really just a limitation of my little laptop? thanks

Comment: This is an extremely localized issue. The manual states in Appendix B-1; `"Some of display modes might not be supported depending on the external monitor which you use."` This may mean you need specific drivers for the monitor. It might be time to contact Toshiba to see if the monitor is supported.

Comment: cool. will look into that. thanks so much for your efforts

Answer (score 0):

try holing down the <kbd>FN</kbd> key at the bottom of the keyboard and press the F5 key to toggle dual screen options. Laptop option not windows 7 ;)